# Close the previous v-dialog when i move to next v-dialog

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

, I am playing with a new vuetify project. I've implemented sign in and signup using a v-dialog and I'm calling those v-dialogs from multiple components. Basically it works for me but I want the previous dialog box to be closed when I click a button to pop up the next v-dialog.

Current Working:

1)A sign in button is placed in navbar. when that button is clicked Sign in v-dialog pops up.

2. On sign in page there's another button which will open a v-dialog where the user can choose type of account. And on choose of a button another v-dialog opens as sign in page.

Solution I need:

A method or logic with which i can close the previous dialog box while new dialog box pops up

Kindly looking forward for some ideas
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If those dialogs are in different components, eventBus maybe the best way to communicate between non-parent-child components:

1. in "main.js":

> ```
> new Vue({
>     data: {
>         eventHub: new Vue()
>     },
>     ...
> }).$mount("#app")
> ```

2. in your dialog component, or the component that contain the dialog:

> ```
> created() {    
>     this.$root.eventHub.$on("close-dialog", () => {
>         do something to close your dialog, such as this.visible = false
>     })
> }
> ```

3. before open your new dialog:

> ```
> this.$root.eventHub.$emit("close-dialog")
> ```